# i'm generating a sine wave using the lut

Tags: vhdl

```
Port ( 
           data_out : out integer range -128 to 127
type ramtype is array (0 downto 29) of integer range -128 to 127;
signal ram : ramtype;
signal sine_wave : ramtype :=(0,16,31,45,58,67,74,77,77,74,67,58,45,31,16,0,
-16,-31,-45,-58,-67,-74,-77,-77,-74,-67,-58,-45,-31,-16);

signal clk :STD_LOGIC;
variable count : integer := 0;
variable inc : integer := 0; 
constant period :time := 10 ms;   -- 100 hz clk frequency 
begin
 process(clk)
 begin
    if rising_edge (clk) then
```

LINE:53    inc <= inc + 1;        -- error
         for i in 0 to 29 loop
            data_out <= sine_wave(count);
            end loop;

```
    end if;
```

end process;

LINE 61:    process(inc)
     begin

```
    clk <= not clk after period/2;

 end process;
```

Line 53: Use := to assign to variable inc
Line 61: Sensitivity list can have only static signal name

I need a concurrent statament for line 53 bu the compiler is suggesting an other thing, and also the sensitivity list is not being accepted
Line 61: Sensitivity list can have only static signal name

Comment: Which one is line 53?

Comment: `inc` is declared as a variable (assignment uses `:=`) and assigned as a signal (uses `<=` assignment).  Only signals belong in sensitivity lists.

Comment: Also, the type `ramtyp`e is declared with a null range (use `to `instead of `downto`)

Comment: The for loop will assign all the same `sinew_wave(count)` value to `data_out` 30 times in one clock. (29 of those projected waveform values will be overwritten, there's only one 'slot' for the current time). Where is`count` incremented?  Both `inc` and `count` should be signals or be declared and only used a single process or should be shared variables.  It isn't clear from your design specification fragment what `inc` is supposed to do for the clock process.

Comment: @DavidKoontz : i want to generate a sine wave where my clk frequency is 100 hz, and i want to sample it accordingly on every posedge of the clock

Comment: @DavidKoontz : sir,one thing I'm unable to figure out : I'm storing some digital values into the ram and displaying it, here I didn't explicitly write a code for sampling and quantization do any sampling and quantization of the analog signal, or am I miss Interpreting anything ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to generate a sine wave where my clk frequency is 100 hz, and i
>   want to sample it accordingly on every posedge of the clock

I did this earlier to find all problems with the portion of your code you did share.  It's still not clear what `inc` was doing in the clock process sensitivity list.

The clock process has been modified to output one complete waveform only.  Note both `inc` and `count` are declared as signals.

The range direction for `ramtype` has been changed from `0 downto 29` to `0 to 29`.

I set the default value for `clk` to '0' which allows not clock to not provide an 'U' (see the not truth table from package std_logic_1164:

```
-- truth table for "not" function
CONSTANT not_table: stdlogic_1d :=
--  -------------------------------------------------
--  |   U    X    0    1    Z    W    L    H    -   |
--  -------------------------------------------------
     ( 'U', 'X', '1', '0', 'X', 'X', '1', '0', 'X' );
```

`clk` has to have an initial value of '0' (or 'L') or '1' ( or 'H') to make the clock process work in simulation.

Your code fragment modified to analyze, elaborate, and simulate:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sinewave is
end entity;

architecture foo of sinewave is

   -- Port (
   --            data_out : out integer range -128 to 127
   signal   data_out: integer range -128 to 127;
   type ramtype is array ( integer range 0 to 29) of  -- was downto
                               integer range -128 to 127;
   -- signal ram : ramtype;
   constant sine_wave: ramtype := ( 
              0, 16, 31, 45, 58, 67, 74, 77, 77, 74, 67, 58, 45, 31, 16,
              0,-16,-31,-45,-58,-67,-74,-77,-77,-74,-67,-58,-45,-31,-16
           );

   signal clk :STD_LOGIC := '0';  --  so not clk gives '1' or '0'
   signal count : integer  range  0 to 29 :=  0;
   signal inc : integer :=  0;     
   constant period :time := 10 ms;   -- 100 hz clk frequency 
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge (clk) then
LINE_53:     inc <= inc + 1;        -- error

            if count = 29 then      -- count  is index pointer to sine_wave
                count <= 0;
            else 
                count <= count + 1;
            end if ;
            -- for i in 0 to 29 loop
            data_out <= sine_wave(count);   
            report "data_out <= " & integer'IMAGE(sine_wave(count));
            --end loop;  
        end if;
     end process;  

LINE_61: process    -- modified to show every element of sine_wave once
    begin           
    wait for period/2;
    clk <= not clk;  -- after period/2;
    if Now > 29.5 * period  then
        wait;
    end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Note how `count` is used as the index to `sine_wave`, so I added an increment to it.  It would seem redundant to have both `inc` and `count`.

The for loop got dropped as I explained in the comment because it doesn't do anything, simply repeating the same `sine_wave` assignment 30 times.  It doesn't affect simulation.

I made his into a test bench because you provided a clock process.

When run the report statements output the `count` indexed `sine_wave` value as a display for purposes of demonstration yielding:

`ghdl -r sinewave
sine.vhdl:37:13:@5ms:(report note): data_out <= 0
sine.vhdl:37:13:@15ms:(report note): data_out <= 16
sine.vhdl:37:13:@25ms:(report note): data_out <= 31
sine.vhdl:37:13:@35ms:(report note): data_out <= 45
sine.vhdl:37:13:@45ms:(report note): data_out <= 58
sine.vhdl:37:13:@55ms:(report note): data_out <= 67
sine.vhdl:37:13:@65ms:(report note): data_out <= 74
sine.vhdl:37:13:@75ms:(report note): data_out <= 77
sine.vhdl:37:13:@85ms:(report note): data_out <= 77
sine.vhdl:37:13:@95ms:(report note): data_out <= 74
sine.vhdl:37:13:@105ms:(report note): data_out <= 67
sine.vhdl:37:13:@115ms:(report note): data_out <= 58
sine.vhdl:37:13:@125ms:(report note): data_out <= 45
sine.vhdl:37:13:@135ms:(report note): data_out <= 31
sine.vhdl:37:13:@145ms:(report note): data_out <= 16
sine.vhdl:37:13:@155ms:(report note): data_out <= 0
sine.vhdl:37:13:@165ms:(report note): data_out <= -16
sine.vhdl:37:13:@175ms:(report note): data_out <= -31
sine.vhdl:37:13:@185ms:(report note): data_out <= -45
sine.vhdl:37:13:@195ms:(report note): data_out <= -58
sine.vhdl:37:13:@205ms:(report note): data_out <= -67
sine.vhdl:37:13:@215ms:(report note): data_out <= -74
sine.vhdl:37:13:@225ms:(report note): data_out <= -77
sine.vhdl:37:13:@235ms:(report note): data_out <= -77
sine.vhdl:37:13:@245ms:(report note): data_out <= -74
sine.vhdl:37:13:@255ms:(report note): data_out <= -67
sine.vhdl:37:13:@265ms:(report note): data_out <= -58
sine.vhdl:37:13:@275ms:(report note): data_out <= -45
sine.vhdl:37:13:@285ms:(report note): data_out <= -31
sine.vhdl:37:13:@295ms:(report note): data_out <= -16`

Your 10 msec clock period means the sine wave is 3.333.. Hz.

Comment: sir,one thing I'm unable to figure out : I'm storing some digital values into the ram and displaying it, here I didn't explicitly write a code for sampling and quantization to do any sampling and quantization of the analog signal, or am I miss Interpreting anything ???

Comment: I would have thought the values for a pure signwave were algorithmically generated. 360 degrees/30 samples = 12 degrees per sample, where the unit is 128 bits, then scaled down.  Where did you get the digital values?

Comment: I surfed the internet and i got it, but I'm not still lucid with the explanation which you have given above, what is the sampling rate.I'm sorry I'm novice, please help me out